# 3 columns in a landscape document with flowfram

Tags: flowfram

I'm trying to create a simple 2 pages document in landscape format, with 3 columns on each page.

I'm trying the `\Ncolumn{3}` command of package `flowfram` because `multicols` refuses float figures inside columns.

Currently my draft is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}

\usepackage[draft]{flowfram}
\ffvadjustfalse
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\Ncolumn{3}

\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{color,graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]
\framebreak

\lipsum[1-2]
\framebreak

\lipsum[1-2]
\framebreak

\clearpage

\lipsum[1-2]
\framebreak

\lipsum[1-2]
\framebreak

\lipsum[1-2]
\framebreak

\end{document}
```

I expected 2 pages with 3 columns on each, instead I'm stuck with 3 pages with 2 columns plus a blank in the middle on each.

Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 11):

There seems to be some incompatibility between `fontspec` and `flowfram`, if you change the order of loading, so `fontspec` is loaded before `flowfram`, it works.

Unrelated note: I don't think there is any point in loading both `color` and `xcolor`, so you can remove the former from your document.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[draft]{flowfram}
\ffvadjustfalse
\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}
\Ncolumn{3}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

[image]